# What's the best solution for CSS typo differences between Windows and Mac?

Tags: css, windows, macos

I was wondering about the CSS differences were ***typography*** position and size, sometimes it doesn't match between windows and mac.

I'm looking the best solution to fix it and it will match the typo between windows and mac.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not just a Mac vs. Windows issue. It's a font vs. font vs. browser vs. browser vs. OS vs. OS vs. device vs. device.

In otherwords, it's the web. Variance is part of the equation. Adapt to it rather than fight it.

Things you can do to lessen the variances:

- utilize CSS resets to give browsers a clean slate
- stick with relatively web safe fonts and consistent font stacks
- leverage CSS3 font-face support to load your own font files

But the big thing to remember is to allow for the variances that are inherent to the medium that is web design.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer... well i'm actually looking for px, em or % for font sizes... i don't know which is better

Comment: There is no 'better' from those sizing options. They all have their uses and when to use which really depends on the context of your particular design/UI implementation. Barring all that, if you want to keep it simple, stick with px.